# How do I make Custom AS3 Classes accessible for data-binding?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding

Assume i have a costum actionscript class.

```
public class myClass

{
       private var myVariable:ArrayCollection;
...
}
```

Suppose also that i have a different class, that changes a second variable, which has the metadatatag [Bindable]. What methods and events do i have to implement in either of these classes, to make myVariable change, whenever the other is changend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `myVariable` public, then you can just use `[BindingUtils.bindProperty()][1]`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public var myVariable:ArrayCollection;

    public function MyClass(other:OtherClass) {

        BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "myVariable", other, "propertyName");

    }
}
```

If you prefer to keep `myVariable` private, then you can use `[BindingUtils.bindSetter()][2]`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private var myVariable:ArrayCollection;

    public function MyClass(other:OtherClass) {

        BindingUtils.bindSetter(
            function(newVal:*):void {
                this.myVariable = newVal;
            }, other, "propertyName");

    }
}
```